# Raster Smoothing python

Tags: python, raster, dem, smoothing

I want to perform raster smoothing on a DEM file. I want to to assign the elevation of each pixel using the average elevations of its 8 neighbors. The ESRI's "Python scripting for ArcGIS" has a chapter on using python for raster but it did not help me to write a code for this. I'm looking for any useful literature, tutorial, or sample code...! please note that r.buffer and r.neighbors is not a good answer for me since I want to learn how to write this code completely.

P.S: I already took a look at [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24933/raster-generalization-buffers-in-rasters-expand-pixels) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31044/qgis-smooth-raster-dem). they did not help me...may be since my knowledge is limited I need more comprehensive answer. Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Comment: You may also want to see http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/9431/1872

Answer (score 0):

Using the [**Python GDAL bindings**](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInPython), you should simply update this example:

http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/lectures/ospy_hw6a.py

Suggestions:

1. use *from osgeo import gdal* instead of *import gdal*
2. import *numpy* (to be installed) instead of *Numeric*;
3. adapt the *outData[i,j]* expression to your need, simply changing the coefficients;
4. some cosmetic corrections in the print messages and...
5. above all, thanks **Chris Garrard**, the author of the [**Geoprocessing with Python using Open Source GIS**](http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/) courses.