# Grid buffer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, buffer, grids-graticules

I do have a raster file (grid) which I have processed before with the SAGA kriging tool. Is it possible to buffer this raster file a little bit (expanding the interpolated result) of 1 or 2 grids? I need to overlap the boundary a little bit.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [Raster generalization - buffers in rasters, expand pixels?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24933/raster-generalization-buffers-in-rasters-expand-pixels).

Comment: Most welcome buddy, although this post may get flagged for being a duplicate =)