# Generalizing slope raster in Mapinfo?

Tags: raster, dem, mapinfo, slope, smoothing

I am working on calculating a slope raster in Mapinfo using a 15cm DEM derived from a LiDAR point cloud and the output data will have 3 predefined breaks displayed so I need to blur those relatively small areas across a larger DEM area fairly accurately.

I've read about [tools which use FFT or Gaussian Blur](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24933/raster-generalization-buffers-in-rasters-expand-pixels) but can't find anything for Mapinfo (64 bit). Can anyone suggest a tool or command that can be used?

edit from comments:

I need to modify the 50cm pixels from their existing value to a value based on a number of surrounding pixels to generalise the slope. I believe this could be achieved using Fast Furier Transform or a Gaussian blur algorithm but I am not aware of which tools/commands to use in Mapinfo 64bit to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MapInfo Pro Advanced, what you want is in the raster tab, [filter tool](http://webhelp.infovista.com/Planet/62/Subsystems/Raster/Content/help/analysis/applyinggridfilters.html).

> The Filter tool can be used to smooth and enhance features in a raster dataset. Filters create output values by applying the specified m x n filter kernel to every cell in the input raster. As the center of the kernel passes over each input cell, the values of that cell and its neighbors are used to calculate the output value for the cell.

There are many types of filters: enhancement, smoothing, focal, etc. The [Gaussian filter](http://webhelp.infovista.com/Planet/62/Subsystems/Raster/Content/help/analysis/smoothing.html) is in the "smoothing" category.

Perhaps you did not find such tool because you are using the MapBasic product (I only found the `filter tool` documented in the MapInfo Pro Advanced).

Comment: Many thanks Andre thats exactly what I missed I juggling using both Mapinfo 11.5 (32 bit) and  Mapinfo Pro 16 (64 bit). I missed the command