# World DEM speckled outcome solution

Tags: qgis, dem, smoothing, world-imagery

I have a world digital elevation model which has been classified into 5 showing the different heights.

My issue is that viewing and printing this image as it is results in a speckled look due to the highs and lows being so close together.

I would like to know a method which can smooth out the speckled look, I would like to print it at multiple sizes showing world heights.

I am using QGIS

[image: World DEM]

Comment: The accepted answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24933/raster-generalization-buffers-in-rasters-expand-pixels) may answer your question.

Comment: SAGA Gaussian Filter seems to somewhat do a smoothening effect.